# Remove lowlatency kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I feel like this should be a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to find answers anywhere online. I installed the lowlatency kernel on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) a while back in order to use my laptop as an amplifier for an electric guitar, but I'm not doing that on this laptop anymore, and the laptop often gets really overworked from doing basic tasks like running Firefox and PyCharm at the same time, so I want to switch back to only using the generic kernel.
How do I uninstall the lowlatency kernel, tell Ubuntu not to install the lowlatency kernel in future, and ensure that it only boots into the generic kernel? I realise that I will need to reboot the laptop into the generic kernel before doing these steps, that's not a problem, I just want to know which steps to take to permanently uninstall the lowlatency kernel, and for some reason I couldn't find any instructions for that. I'm happy to provide the output of any commands if needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove lowlatency kernel
`sudo apt remove linux-image-<version number>-lowlatency`
Install generic kernel
`sudo apt install linux-image-<version number>-generic`